# IPsec VPN between Fortigate 60C and openswan up, but no traffic

Tags: configuration, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, openswan, fortigate

I get visual confirmation that the tunnel is working from the fortigate GUI but, it also says i don't have 1 byte of traffic, the linux server also confirms the tunnel is open but i can't ping nowhere,

my conn

```
conn office
 #left side is home
 left=%defaultroute
 leftsubnet=192.168.3.0/24
 #right side is work
 #set right to vpn remote gateway
 right=201.174.xxx.xxx
 #set rightsubnet to remote network
 rightsubnet=192.168.1.0/24
 keyexchange=ike
 #auth=esp
 #auto=start
 authby=secret
 #specify encryption FortiGate VPN uses
 esp=3des
 #perfect forward secrecy (default yes)
 #pfs=no
 #optionally enable compression
 compress=yes
```

the fortigate status
[image: Vpn Status]

ping test :

```
-- 192.168.1.254 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6000ms
```

on the fortigate I did add the nesesary routes and policies as stated in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a virtual machine to test the vpn, that was a mistake, since my modem had no physical interface for the virtual machine, it assumed it was on port 2 and gave dmz access to port 2 while my physical computer containing the virtual machine was on port 1, after wrtitting my virtual machine to a physical unit, and configuring DMZ the vpn started transfering.